# How to apply condition in filtering from Mysql using list of values

Tags: python, mysql, django

Db table

```
          verystrong   strong   moderate   weak    veryweak

US             aa          a       ba         b       caa 
UK             aa          a       baa        b       caa
Austria        a           baa     ba         caa     ca
Belgium        a           baa     ba         caa     ca
Japan          aa          a       baa        b       caa
UAE            ba          b       b          b1      c


country='UK'
traderow=exporttable.objects.filter(ratio=country).values()[0]
```

`traderow` output:

```
{'id': 2, 'ratio': 'UK', 'verystrong': 'aa', 'strong': 'a', 
'moderate': 'baa', 'weak': 'b', 'veryweak': 'caa'}
```

next i have **the list**  `a`

```
a=['verystrong','verystrong','strong','strong','strong','strong','strong']
```

`a` is rating made for years from 2013 to 2019 e.g 2019 rating is strong , in 2013 is strong.

Now i want for each value in the list to match with value in traderow to find trade rating:

I can return only one value from **the list** at a time:

```
value1=a[0] whihc is 'verystrong' (year 2013) 
value7=a[6] whihc is 'strong' (year 2019)
```

`trade_rating2013=traderow[value1]` which returns for year **2013** `aa`
`trade_rating2019=traderow[value7]` which returns for year **2019** `a`

My question is how to implement this operation effectively for the whole list not implemneting for each value in the list seperately ? is that possible to apply lambda ?

I am still learning python and would appreciate your help to optimize the code to remove redundancy and make it more effecient.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you problem well, then this is what you want:

```
traderow = {
    "id": 2,
    "ratio": "UK",
    "verystrong": "aa",
    "strong": "a",
    "moderate": "baa",
    "weak": "b",
    "veryweak": "caa",
}

a = ["verystrong", "verystrong", "strong", "strong", "strong", "strong", "strong"]

for item, year in zip(a, range(2013, 2020)):
    print(f"trade_rating for {year}: {traderow[item]}")
```

As you said if you don't want to print you just want to store them.

```
trade_rating = [traderow[item] for item in a]
```

### Output:

```
trade_rating for 2013: aa
trade_rating for 2014: aa
trade_rating for 2015: a
trade_rating for 2016: a
trade_rating for 2017: a
trade_rating for 2018: a
trade_rating for 2019: a
```

Comment: can you please remove years i only need list a. When i remove it does not work anyway and creates raise error search probloem howvere no such problem when i search seperately

Comment: i tried this but not working good : for item a : b=traderow[item]

Comment: i do not want to print them i want them to be a value i can further use in formula. I use django

Comment: hey you copied from @Günel asnwer.  I can see timing )